# Mixed network plot with geographical points on map while non geographical vertices outside the map

Tags: r, plot

What I'm looking forward is something like this:

[image]

I want the geographical(29 states points in the case) presented on the maps, with a mass amount users out side it.

All the examples I've found with `leaflet` package, `igraph` and `ggmaps` package is merely edges on maps or networks beside map. The only idea I have is to give the non geographical vertices a set of restricted lat/lon coordinates, for examples throw them to the Antarctic Pole.

I think there may be some method better to solve the problems.

Comment: Did you try to apply your idea - "throw them to the Antarctic Pole"?

Comment: For sure. since deadline approached I'll have to use this back up plan by the end of this week.

Comment: It is a good practice to share code with reproducible example data: [info about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: what do you mean by a 'better method' ? what's wrong with the approach you're suggesting?